# Infinity in MSVC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point, infinity

I'm using MSVC++, and I want to use the special value INFINITY in my code.

What's the byte pattern or constant to use in MSVC++ for infinity?

Why does 1.0f/0.0f appear to have the value 0?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
  float zero = 0.0f ;
  float inf = 1.0f/zero ;

  printf( "%f\n", inf ) ; // 1.#INF00
  printf( "%x\n", inf ) ; // why is this 0?

  printf( "%f\n", zero ) ; // 0.000000
  printf( "%x\n", zero ) ; // 0

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

```
#include <limits>

float maxFloat = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
```

Comment: Neat!  How does this work?  Is it ok to assign something `numeric_limits<float>::infinity()`?  What is the bit pattern for INFINITY?  How does it know if the pattern is apparently 0 in my example?

Comment: @bobobobo: When you treat a variable as something it's not in `printf`, there isn't much to expect, it could break. I think peterchen covers it.

Answer (score 11):

`printf("%x\n", inf)` expects an integer (32 bit on MSVC), but receives a double. Hilarity will ensue. Err, I mean: undefined behavior.

(And yes, it receives a double since for a variable argument list, floats are promoted to double).

Edit anyways, you should use `numeric_limits`, as the other reply says, too.

Answer (score 3):

In the variable arguments list to printf, floats get promoted to doubles.  The little-endian byte representation of infinity as a double is 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 7F.

As peterchen mentioned, "%x" expects an int, not a double.  So printf looks at only the first sizeof(int) bytes of the argument.  No version of MSVC++ defines int to be larger than 4 bytes, so you get all zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`numeric_limits::infinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hthw3cb%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

That's what happens when you lie to printf(), it gets it wrong.  When you use the %x format specifier, it expects an integer to be passed on the stack, not a float passed on the FPU stack.  Fix:

```
printf( "%x\n", *(__int32*)&inf ) ;
```

You can get infinity out of the `<limits>` C++ header file:

```
float inf = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity().
```